# Send proactive chat message to initiator of Microsoft Teams Calling Bot voice caller

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a teams bot that can answer 1-to-1 voice calls.  During the call I want the bot to be able to send chat messages to the user and be able to reference user data (like their name).

Although an incoming call does have a encrypted source identity, from my experiments it appears this is not a valid user id for proactive messaging.

Interestingly enough this is easily possible in group calls as it starts passing you participant lists (which i've done before), but 1-to-1 calls appear to rely on the source field which effectively leaves the user as anonymous.

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
      "changeType": "created",
      "resource": "/app/calls/4a1f2c00-831f-4e4e-9d7c-1648b6dddb73",
      "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/4a1f2c00-831f-4e4e-9d7c-1648b6dddb73",
      "resourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
        "state": "incoming",
        "direction": "incoming",
        "callbackUri": "https://...",
        "source": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.participantInfo",
          "id": "7684a0ea-7db6-4f3e-a339-eb46e16d57f0",
          "identity": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
            "encrypted": {
              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
              "id": "1g7qrdwga2udafuebrjcyobchnq7r4xigupowjluuccfdceufmew6ush6wlx-kellf96ky2nnhsl084rn6vegqmwawiqpux0kk5aw5lqq9oydrewxe9awkrk_uh_0nxat", // <-- not a valid chat user
              "tenantId": "{tenancyId}",
              "identityProvider": "None"
            }
          },
          "endpointType": "default",
          "region": "apac",
          "languageId": "en-us"
        },
        "targets": [
          {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
            "identity": {
              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
              "application": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                "id": "a2716ab5-9b38-4364-8869-b9b8deeff897",
                "identityProvider": "AAD"
              }
            },
            "endpointType": "default",
            "id": "023126f0-904f-4c01-a78d-03f28e77e7a7",
            "region": null,
            "languageId": null
          }
        ],
        "tenantId": "{Azure Tenancy}",
        "myParticipantId": "023126f0-904f-4c01-a78d-03f28e77e7a7",
        "callChainId": "37de77c7-54b3-4d04-9e9c-181e5f5b5773",
        "incomingContext": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.incomingContext",
          "sourceParticipantId": "7684a0ea-7db6-4f3e-a339-eb46e16d57f0"
        },
        "id": "4a1f2c00-831f-4e4e-9d7c-1648b6dddb73"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @betty, we have gone through your issue and we need some more information. Shall we have a quick call, could you please let us know your available time.

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT I live in New Zealand, so timezone might be interesting. How does this work?

Comment: Hi @betty, could you please try with this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/HueBot/HueBot)

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT hi, that looks like it requires a meeting call with another person, and not a direct call to the bot?

Comment: Hi @Betty, we cannot make a direct call to the bot, instead we can install/invite bot  for a meeting in the conversation.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT direct calls are completely possible to bots, that's what the supportsCalling flag in the manifest enables.  It's just that the notifiation that comes through for that call didn't seem to have identity data I could make use of.

Comment: now it may well be that my use case is not intended, but it does feel a bit odd that an incoming call doesn't get user information that's useful, even if it's not possible to use it for proactive messaging.

Comment: You will receive the user info in the turncontext.activity.from. Please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/blob/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/RemoteMediaSamples/IncidentBot/Bot/Bot.cs) for more info.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT wouldn't that require a chat activity rather than a phone call?

Comment: Hi @Betty, We can get the user information from turncontext.activity, that doesn't require a phone call.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I know about turn context, but I don't think that helps in this case. I am purposely using a human to bot call and want to integrate that interaction with the chat. I can do this in a group call, but not one to one.

Comment: If you want to call to a bot then you can use bot id to initiate the call, If you are trying to call user from bot use the user id.

Comment: I want to manually call the bot from teams, then when it answers the call i want to be able to send chat messages from the bot to the user.  I need both voice and messaging for my idea to work.

Comment: Is there an update to this issue?   Additionally, is the calling a bot feature still only available in developer preview?

Comment: @Ennova i gave up on the idea.  However I believe there's a couple new graphapis that have come out since I looked at this which may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can able to send the chat messages by creating Responder Call handler from bot.
Could you please try to implement the [sample code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/blob/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/RemoteMediaSamples/IncidentBot/Bot/ResponderCallHandler.cs).
In the sample code, will have a class named "ResponderCallHandler.cs", please have a look.

Comment: Looking at that code I don't see anything that looks like it sends a chat message.  Is there a specific line you're looking at?